# Python socket connection between Raspberry Pi’s

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I’m a beginner to programming. Im currently trying to create an alarm system using two Raspberry Pi’s. I figured out how to set up a socket connection and send over a tcp from the client to the server.

Now the question: how do I set up different ‘types of tcp’ so that I call function:

`StartAlarm()` on `RPI1(client)` will call function `StartAlarm()` to run on `RPI2(server)`  and

`StopAlarm()` on `RPI1(client)` will call `StopAlarm()` to run `onRPI2(server)`

Please feel free to correct my grammar and spelling :)

Comment: @Laurent I tried multiple sending scripts on RPI1 with multiple receiving scripts on RPI2 while matching them with the same ports but it didn’t seem te work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a thread or a subprocess which is constantly waiting for thoses message instructions, so if the message in the socket is `None` do nothing if the message is `'stop the alarm'` then do `stopAlarm()` else if the message is `'start the alarm'` then do `startAlarm()`. Since you have not show what you have done this far, this is all I can do to help you. I hope it helps !

**update**:

**On RPI1 :**

```
import socket

def sendTCP(message=''):
   HOST, PORT = "192.168.43.136", 9999
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   try:
      sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
   except socket.error:
      pass
   else:
      sock.send(message) #the message is the order
   sock.close()
```

**On RPI2 :**

```
import socket
import threading


def start_server(host='', port=1060):
   global sock_server
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
   s.bind((host, port))
   s.listen(1)
   while True:
      sock_server, sockname = s.accept()
      break


def receiveTCP(sock):
   message = sock.recv(32)
   return message


def stopAlarm():
   pass


def startAlarm():
   pass


class OrderWaiter(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(OrderWaiter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   def run(self):
      global sock_server
      while True:
         try:
            message = receiveTCP(sock_server)
         except Exception:
            pass
         else:
            if message != '':
               if message == 'stop alarm':
                  stopAlarm()
               elif message == 'start alarm':
                  startAlarm()
               sock_server.close()
               break

if __name__ == '__main__':
   sock_server = None
   start_server() # pass the host and the port as parameters
   OrderWaiter().start() #start the thread which will wait for the order
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This maybe is a really stupid question, but how do I put an message like ‘stop the alarm’ inside the tcp that is send to the server.

Comment: if the socket is `sock` then you can send that by `sock.send('stop the alarm')`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5P5VUDAk This is what I am currently using, where should I put the code?